# React Victory chart displays different line lengths for straight lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

I'm using [the Victory library](http://formidable.com/open-source/victory/) to draw a line chart in React, but it seems to draw lines with different widths depending on whether the line is straight or is at an angle.

Screenshot of the line it's drawing:

[image]

In the screenshot, the dots are drawn using `VictoryScatter` and the line(s) using `VictoryLine`. I noticed that `VictoryLine` draws using `path`, so is this a limitation of SVG's `path` to draw like this? Because this seems weird to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the order or rendering of the SVG components. The ones at the top and the bottom appear to be thinner because they are rendered *behind* the axes (this is explained [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/layout/#svg-render-order))

I'm not sure why, but changing the order didn't work for me, so I had to use [VictoryPortal](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-portal/) to bring my components to the front.